# Run cypress commands interactively

Tags: javascript, cypress

Is there a possibility to open a browser and run cypress test commands interactively? Similar to using the *scripts* tab in chrome devtools. It takes too long time to start the browser run the tests each time.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-select-tests)?

Comment: I have this exact same issue. The "re-run" functionality doesn't work for me because I'm modifying a really complex test, so re-running it just takes a lot of my time to simply run a command.

I'm looking for a way to simply input a command like "cy.get('element').click" and either work or tell me it wouldn't, so I can see what works and avoid waiting for an entire "re-run".

Comment: I tried doing it, but since cypress commands are not javascript - they are not recognized in the chrome console as executable functions.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the pain. But to my best knowledge the auto-scan feature of cypress takes care of 're-run' of the tests as you update them. In other words, you launch the test only once using cypress open command and every time you update a test or tests, cypress UI will auto-refresh to fetch latest test code. If you changes made in a file that is being executed, then the active run will re-run automatically.

This feature is enabled by default, but for some reason is not working, check your **env.json** file and see below line points to true. For further reading refer [cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Command-Line)

```
{
   watchForFileChanges: true
}
```

Coming to the injecting code from browser part, I don't think that is an option with cypress.